# Accidentally Broke Site (Please Help)

Tags: plugins, errors

Hi I accidentally broke my site when I added the WP Date Remover. After I installed it and clicked activate the site went down and says "This page isn’t working [site name] is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500". Do you know how I can fix this or remove the plugin if the site is down? Or anyone I could talk to who can help me with this? Please help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Via FTP, go into the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder and delete the `wp-date-remover/` folder. That will disable the plugin on the code level.

If you need help with FTP, visit your web host control panel and navigate around, view their docs, andor talk to their support.

(A very good reminder to always back up your website!)

Answer (score -2):

Simply login to cpnale and go to file manager or use FTP. Then navigate wp-content/plugins folder then rename or delete `wp-date-remover` folder and you should be able to see the site live again